# iPhone Safari landscape orientation CSS issue

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari

If you take a look at my simple site, it works great in browser, but on an iphone the site loses the bottom ribbon in landscape orientation.

Why is it not correctly adjusting the height of the page when in landscape?
http://mtindustrialservicerequest.com/KenHolidayCard/holidayCardDemo/EmployeeCard2.html

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</HEAD>
<BODY style="text-align: center; background-color:#e4e4e4; background-image:url(snowflakeBackground500x500.png); margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-image:url(ribbon_Bottom2.png); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: center center;">
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height:325px; overflow: visible; top: 50%; margin-top: -170px; background-image:url(ribbon_Horizontal2.png); background-position: center center;">
<iframe width="650" height="325" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bFs89lAL7dE?&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=0&theme=light&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by stacking three divs on top of each other -- top and bottom ribbon with video and horizontal ribbon in the middle. Top and bottom heights at 50% with bottom/top margins to compensate for the 325px video in the middle. See below.

```
<BODY style="text-align: center; background-color:#e4e4e4; background-image:url(snowflakeBackground500x500.png); margin:0; padding:0;">
<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<div id="div2" style="position: relative; height: 50%; width: 100%; margin-bottom:-170px; background-image:url(ribbon_Bottom2.png); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: center center;"></div>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height:325px; overflow: visible; background-image:url(ribbon_Horizontal2.png); background-position: center center;">
<iframe class="shadow" width="650" height="325" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bFs89lAL7dE?&autoplay=1&rel=0&fs=0&theme=light&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1&color=white" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="div3" style="position: relative; height: 50%; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 170px; background-image:url(ribbon_Bottom2.png); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: center center;"></div>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually disappearing altogether. After rotating from portrait to landscape, I hit refresh. It was visible (well about 8 pixels of it).

I would add `min-height:320px` to your CSS for the vertical ribbon. 320 or another value you can work with.

Comment: This didn't work exactly as I expected. The value had to be set to 850px (I'm not sure why) in order to fill the landscape screen from top to bottom. 850px creates issues when the site is viewed in a web browser.

Comment: You could use a media query to solve for mobile - just a thought. @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 .vertRibbon { height:XX; min-height:XX ... }
}